# Can Javascript be used to detect a redirected image SRC (in any popular browser)?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm guessing nope, but you never know.

1. Browser loads `<img src="http://example.net/lolcat.png">`
2. example.net redirects `lolcat.png` to `http://static.example.net/bandwidth-exceeded.gif`

Can I detect this?

Cross-browser isn't important, just looking for an option that will work in any 1 popular browser.

So far my best option is knowing the size of the placeholder image, getting a "maybe" by looking at the image size onload (in browsers that support onload events in image tags), and making a quick XHR request notifying the backend that we've got a maybe.

Comment: Mmmmm... Interesting question. How about the `src` property in such a case. Doesn't it / shouldn't it change? I can't test right now.

Comment: yeah.. the src property always returns what it was set to originally.

Answer (score 6):

I checked with the following code:

```
var a=new Image(); a.src='http://example.com/image.png';
alert( a.width );
```

which in this case returns 0 since the image doesn't exist.

On [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347092(VS.85).aspx) I found quite a few properties that might be worth checking out. And if that fails you might want to look into jQuery and AJAX.

**Edit**:
   <sub>tested on firefox firebug</sub>

```
var a=new Image(); 
a.src='http://l.yimg.com/g/images/photo_unavailable_m.gif';
console.log(a.width); // the image exists and returns 240

var b=new Image(); 
b.src='http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2560/4098180849_729ef4f6ef_m.jpg';
console.log(b.width); // the image does not exist (re-direct) and returns 0
```

Comment: Do you have a sample image that is redirected so I can test this out?

Comment: hm. That's interesting. When an image is redirected, I'd expect to get the size and not 0... but maybe Image can tell me something. It looks like IE might be able to report the file size, which is interesting.  Here is an example: http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2560/4098180849_729ef4f6ef_m.jpg is redirected to http://l.yimg.com/g/images/photo_unavailable_m.gif

Comment: Sweet! Accepted. **edit** oh wait. When I do this in Firebug, the second example gives me 240 and not 0.

Answer (score 4):

the answer to your question
Can Javascript be used to detect a redirected image SRC (in any popular browser)?
is simple as you said , nope! because http doesnt have any option for identifying the redirection. This is similar to detecting url redirection, which is simply a limitation for javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to detect a redirect with JavaScript without some previous knowledge of the image properties. The src property of the current DOM will remain the same regardless of any redirect, so that option is out.

I would suggest that you create a proxy script on your server that acts as a go between. For example, your image tag would look something like (with suitable URL encoding, of course):

```
<img src='/proxy?src=http://example.com/image.png' />
```

Your proxy script would inspect the headers for redirects before serving the image. It isn't fool proof - but it could allow you to, for example, cache the image on first load so you don't get bandwidth limit errors from the other machine.

If it is just for your own purposes, you might be able to use an ActiveXObject within Internet Explorer to inspect the image in more detail. Can't help you on the specifics though.

*I assume that you're permitted to hotlink/cache the image with the permission of the other party.*

Answer (score 0):

> example .net redirects lolcat.png to
>   http://static.example.net/bandwidth-exceeded.gif

What is lolcat.png? I'm guessing its a Handler and essentially it just does this:

<%
Response.Redirect("bandwidth-exceeded.gif?redirect=true")
 %>

If so, have your tried Helicon's ISAPI URL Rewrite, create a regex rule to append a query string param onto the end of the image's URL

Comment: hm.. I'm not sure where you're going with this - example.net is some outside site not controlled by me.

Comment: so you dont even know what lolcat.png is? doh! does it have to be via javascript? I'm thinking perhaps you could make a handler for your images http://dotnetperls.com/ashx then try and get the referrer, eg: HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer().ToString(), then if it has to be detected via javascript maybe you could write the referrer value to a hidden html textbox.

Comment: ps I'm not sure the referrer will allow you to detect if its come from a redirection, but if it aint from lolcat.png can you then assume it isn't a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript, it's impossible. But with help of server side script (such PHP), it can be easily done. I've made my own free service at http://finalurl.web44.net, useful to resolve simple URL redirection.

To use it, include `finalURL.js` from within HEAD section, *i.e.*

```
<script src="http://finalurl.web44.net/finalURL.js"></script>
```

To use it, call `finalURL( url_to_resolve );` function, *i.e.*

```
var actualURL = finalURL( 'http://dummy.com/beforeRedirectURL.jpg' );
```

If you want to host the back-end PHP code by yourself, check following post:
[Find redirected img source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598254/find-redirected-img-source)