# Prevent a redirect with http image tag src

Tags: javascript, html, api, http, https

In my webpage I have a image tag with a source that gets an image from an api over an https connection, sometimes this request failes and redirects to an error image on an http connection giving the user an warning some of the webpages parts are on an insecure connection. is there a way to prevent the browser to use the unsecure link or change it to download it over https with javascript somehow.

```
<img src="https://example.com/image_320x240.png"/>
```

The api doesn't always have an image ready so it will redirect to

```
<img src="http://example.com/error_320x240.png"/>
```

the error image is also available on https but I don't know how make the browser use it using js or check the url before downloading the image.

Comment: Why not just change the protocol to https for the error image, as long as you control the server the image is hosted on, and can use SSL.

Comment: Maybe try to load the image with JS

Comment: I am not in controll over the server the api is hosted on

Comment: Could you provide us with your code?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4082696/2913356. You could create a proxy to detect redirects and insecure connections. In HTML it is not possible to detect redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you serve up your own error image if the above image isn't ready?

Maybe something like this:

```
function populateImage(url, element) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', url);
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
      var img = document.createElement('img')
      if (req.status === 200) {
        img.src = url;
      } else {
        img.src = 'https://path.to.my.errorImage';
      }
      element.appendChild(img);
    }
  };
  req.send();
}



<p id='placeholder'></p>
populateImage('https://exmple.com/320x240.png',document.getElementById('placeholder'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve the problem by loading the image via JavaScript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function(e) {
  // Do something on error. Load other image?
}
img.onload = function() {
  if (this.src.match(/https:/)) {
    document.getElementById('foo').src = this.src;
  } else {
    this.src = this.src.replace('http:', 'https:');
  }
};
img.src = 'https://example.com/image_320x240.png';
```

Your image elements in html will look something like:

```
<img src="" alt="" id="foo" />
```

What the code does is loading an image via javascript. If the image is loaded, the url of the loaded image is checked. If the url is secure, then the image is shown by assigning it to an element in your DOM. If not, the insecure url is changed to a secure one and the image from the new url is loaded.

I hope this helps you further.