# Angular <img [src]="someURL"> How can I get access to the redirected URL in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In an Angular application, I'm having the image src be a custom URL, for example, `https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?facebook`, this gets redirected to some image hosted on their server.

In some cases the result URL will redirect to a bad image, for example, `https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?roblox` will redirect to `https://images.unsplash.com/source-404?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=60&w=1200` every time there is no good result for a term (i.e. roblox, in this case, was a bad term).

How can I get access to this redirected URL in my code?

What I've Already Tried:

I pass the HTMLInputElement to my TypeScript by `<img [src]="someFunctionReturningURL(t)" #t>`.
Inside `someFunctionReturningURL(t)`, I call a `setTimeout` (to ensure the `img` has fully loaded the `src` URL) and test if `t.src == "https://images.unsplash.com/source-404?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&q=60&w=1200"` but the problem is `t.src` still holds the original unredirected link `https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?roblox` and not the link it actually gets redirected to!

Comment: An image request being redirected does not cause the `src` attribute of the DOM element to be updated.

Comment: You could do a manual request to the url and check where are you redirected, and then set the src with the final url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Javascript be used to detect a redirected image SRC (in any popular browser)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082513/can-javascript-be-used-to-detect-a-redirected-image-src-in-any-popular-browser)

Comment: I tried the link Terry sent, it's a nice hack for my specific situation since on a bad URL it would redirect to a 1200 width image instead of 1600 as I requested, so I could tell immediately if it was bad. But the answer below is more universal and gets the actual redirected URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fetch method to get redirected url then set that on src attribute:

```
fetch("https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?facebook")
  .then(res => {
    if (res.url) {
      this.imageSrc = res.url;
      console.log(this.imageSrc);
    }
  });
```

[Example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5x65vw1nwl?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)